# Spacebars for HTML ‘disabled’ HTML input

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm disabling `textareas` using the `disabled` HTML property.

```
<textarea disabled>{{foo}}</textarea>
```

Simple enough. That enables it so that the client cannot enter the textarea and make changes. However, I want to make that `disabled` based on a conditional.

Let's say `allowed` is a Boolean. I want to just be able to do the following.

```
<textarea {{#unless allowed}} disabled  {{/unless}}>{{foo}}</textarea>
```

But this causes errors in the template. In VS Code the `{{#unless allowed}}disabled{{` turns blue and the `/unless}}` turns red.

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know blaze/spacebars, but after a quick look into its documentation, it seems like it does not support its logic inside attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you need to use a so-called [attribute helper](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Attribute-Helpers).

```html
<textarea {{attributes}}>{{foo}}</textarea>
```

```js
Template.foo.helpers({
  attributes() {
    return {
      disabled: allowed,
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: So `allowed` is actually a property on a Document. I pass in `Document` to the helper method. But...I get `cannot read property of undefined`. I think this happens because the `Document` does not exist when the template gets created (but it will when the template gets rendered). I solve this by simply checking for existence of `Document && Document._id` prior to checking for `allowed`. I'm just wondering if there's a better way/

Comment: yes, that is right. Both in terms of analysis and approach. That's the way to do it. It's important to think "reactively", so that approach is good.